# How to alter a field within an unlimited field collection?

Tags: entities

I am trying to set the `#access` attribute to `FALSE` on a field that is within an unlimited field collection - so it is hidden from users. I am relatively new to Drupal so I'm not sure how to handle this. I tried to use `hook_form_alter` and some basic CSS - but I couldn't get either of the solution to work properly because of the unlimited field cardinality.

Here's what worked for one row in the field collection in a custom module:

```
$form['field_my_field_collection']['und'][0]['field_myfield']['#access'] = FALSE;
```

How do you alter a specific field in a field collection with unlimited values? Thanks in advance for any help - the Drupal community is awesome.

Comment: Yes Drupal community is awesome :)

Comment: have you tried using a for loop something like foreach($form['field_my_field_collection']['und'] as $field)

Comment: Did you look at the field permissions module? http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions

Answer (score 6):

Since Drupal 7.8 you can leverage [hook_field_widget_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form_alter/7). You can alter any field widgets provided by field_collection before the form_alter of the main form.

```
function my_module_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  if ("field_my_field_collection" == $element['#bundle']) {
    if ("field_my_field_collection" == $element['#field_name']) {
      $element['#access'] = FALSE;
    }
  }
// dpm(array($element, $form_state, $context), "field_name: " . $element['#field_name'] );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your help Mohammed, but I ended up using the following code in a custom module:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
if($form_id == 'myformid') {
$delta = 0;
$max_delta = $form['field_my_field_collection'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#max_delta'];
while ($delta <= $max_delta) {
$form['field_my_field_collection'][LANGUAGE_NONE][$delta]['field_myfield']   
[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#access'] = FALSE;
  $delta++;
    }
  }
}
```