# how to make checkbox checked by default in add content type form

Tags: 7, nodes

Hi i had created 1 content type. In this content type I have created a field called courses of type field collections. In the field collections I have added 1 fields of type checkbox which I want to be enabled by default. there is option to do by configuration. But I want to do it by coding . How to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can this using Drupal's [Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x). You'll have to alter the form and set the value.

```
function modulename_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){

switch($form_id){
        case "your_form":

           $form['cbs'] = array(
           '#type' => 'checkboxes',
           '#options' => array(1 => "One", 2 => "Two", 3 => "Three"),
           '#default_value' => array(1, 3),
           );

        break;
        }
}
```

**To know more about altering form check the below links:**

1. http://befused.com/drupal/form-alter
2. http://themery.com/dgd7/advanced-theming/forms/with-alter-hooks

**UPDATE:**

If field collections try using [widget_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form_alter/7.x):

```
function my_module_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {

 if ("field_my_field_collection" == $element['#bundle']) {

    if ("field_my_field_collection" == $element['#field_name']) {

         //do your work here
    }
  }
}
```

**There are two related questions in the following links, which may help you:**

1. [Question One.](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/118347/how-to-form-alter-fields-attached-to-an-unlimited-field-collection)
2. [Question Two.](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/59751/how-to-alter-a-field-within-an-unlimited-field-collection)

Comment: Hii, it is working for fields of that content type. But as I mentioned I Created 1 course field of type field collection.in the field collection I have added 1 checkbox. That checkbox I want to be enabled by default.

Comment: @shailjaranjan I have added further details.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($form_id == 'course_page_node_form') {   
$form['field_course_tabs'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['field_enable_in_tab'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#default_value'] = 1;
```

}
this one worked for me.